# Do aboriginal Australians value the acknowledgement of country speeches

Tags: australia, indigenous-people

Before many formal presentations often that have some connection with the government there is a formal acknowledgement of the traditional owners of the area and the tribe.

This is usually in the form below and can be more general as can be found [here](https://www.vic.gov.au/aboriginalvictoria/heritage/welcome-to-country-and-acknowledgement-of-traditional-owners.html) in a Victorian government information page

> 'Our meeting/conference/workshop is being held on the traditional
>   lands [or country] of the [Traditional Owner group's name] people and
>   I wish to acknowledge them as Traditional Owners.
>
> I would also like to pay my respects to their Elders, past and
>   present, and the Elders from other communities who may be here today.'

What I want to know is, are these acknowledgements valued by Australian indigenous people or is it seen as an empty statement?

Comment: Why do you assume the perception is monolithic?  Some indigenous people may value these.  Others may view it as political hot air.

Comment: I personally don't assume it's monolithic like any groups there is variation. Perceptions about groups are often monolithic so that's why I left the question that way. My hope is that the answer addresses these details.

Comment: It's an empty gesture. The Aboriginal people have long lost their land to European invaders and nothing can change that.

Answer (score 4):

### Generally yes

While I don't know a whole lot about it myself, according to some poking around on the internet, this is what some elders have to say:

> I think it's fantastic [to do Acknowledgement of Country ceremonies], ten years ago we weren't even acknowledged.

-- Warren Mundine

Further, politicians continue to back it.

> [Acknowledgement of Country] says to the world, and more importantly to ourselves, that we accept the fact we are in a place that has a history and story far beyond 220 years. It says to our Aboriginal and Torres Strait Islander fellow Australians that we are all in the future journey of our country together.

-- Richard Wynne, Victorian Minister for Aboriginal Affairs

[Source](https://www.creativespirits.info/aboriginalculture/spirituality/welcome-to-country-acknowledgement-of-country#ixzz5TCUh5Dcn)